# Azure Portal: Your operation could not be completed successfully

Tags: database, azure, azureportal

I am trying to add my IP address to "Networking"  in Azure Portal, so I can access my database and I get this error:

[image]

I have looked at the Activity Log but I do not see any usable information. Does anybody have an idea of why I can not update?
I can also note that my internet connection is good.

Comment: It might take some time to reflect in activity logs... can you provide more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

- We have reproduced in our environment and got the same error. It may be because of the Invalid IP Address Format
- Added the Invalid IP, got the below error

[image]

Please check your valid IP Address range and add accordingly.

- As mentioned by @[Gandhi], yes it takes some time to get the refreshed Activity Log.
- We got the failed Activity log after some time
  [image]